# How to form properly __soapCall parameters

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

Trying to make a soap call with parameters:

```
$client = new SoapClient( null, [
    'location'   => $url,
    'uri'        => $uri,
    'trace'      => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1
] );

$params['parameters'] = [
    'p1'=>'v1',
    'p2'=>'v2'
];

$client->__soapCall('generate',$params);
```

I want my request look like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="some_url_here">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:generate>
            <parameters>
                <p1>v1</p1>
                <p2>v2</p2>
            </parameters>
        </ns1:generate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But what I get is:

```
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="some_url_here"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:generate>
        <param0 xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">p1</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">v1</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">p2</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">v2</value>
            </item>
        </param0>
    </ns1:generate>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas how properly form params list to get wanted request? 
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The best and fast way to consume a Soap Web Service is to use a WSDL to php generator as you won't wonder how to construct the request.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project and you'll see it's easy to construct the request (without making any error unless you're doing it purposely ;)). In addition, the received response is easily handled. Each part is an object.